# incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function logl

Tags: gcc, cygwin

When I compile this short program

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
        long double ld = logl(1L);
        printf("logl = %Lf\n", ld);
}
```

using 'gcc foo.c' I get this error message

```
 $ gcc foo.c
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:5:19: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘logl’
  long double ld = logl(1L);
```

The include file math.h is being included from /usr/include/math.h

```
$ gcc -M foo.c
foo.o: foo.c /usr/include/math.h /usr/include/sys/reent.h \
 /usr/include/_ansi.h /usr/include/newlib.h /usr/include/sys/config.h \
....
```

prototype of logl() is found inside math.h

```
$ grep logl /usr/include/math.h
extern long double logl _PARAMS((long double));
```

The compilation error message indicates compiler is not able to find
prototype of logl().

Definition of logl() inside math.h is surrounded by these ifndefs

```
#ifndef _REENT_ONLY
#ifndef __math_6888
...
extern long double logl _PARAMS((long double));
...
#endif /* ! defined (__math_68881) */
#endif /* ! defined (_REENT_ONLY) */
```

I am not defining any of these symbols through command line parameters of gcc.
Therefore, I expect gcc to find the prototype of logl() but for some reason it is unable to.

Also, if change the program to use log(1) instead of logl(1L), there is no
compiler error about 'incompatible implicit declaration'. gcc is able to
find log() but not logl() inside math.h. log() is declared within same
ifndefs that surrounds logl().

I am compiling in cygwin which has version 4.9.3 of gcc.